# Live Reload using webpack-plugin-serve is not working

Tags: webpack, livereload

I'm currently learning how to use Webpack. I'm [following the SurviveJS Webpack 5 book/tutorial](https://survivejs.com/webpack/developing/development-server/) that uses `webpack-plugin-serve` as the dev server, but I can't get the Live Reload functionality to work in my browser.

I see a lot of questions on this topic where the users are running `webpack-dev-server`, and those answers don't solve my problem.

## **SETUP:**

**ENVIRONMENT:**

- Windows 11 OS
- VS Code v1.84.2
- Node v18.18.0
- Google Chrome (up to date, version 119.0.6045.160)

**FILE STRUCTURE:**

```
webpack-demo/
| + dist/    
| | - index.html    
| | - main.js
| + node_modules/
| + public/
| | - bundle.js
| | - index.html
| + src/
| | - component.js
| | - index.js
| package-lock.json
| package.json
| webpack.config.js
```

## **PROBLEM**

**EXPECTED BEHAVIOR:**

1. In my terminal, execute `npm run start` which runs the app in development mode.
2. Open the app in Chrome at `127.0.0.1:8080`, to see the webpage read "Hello World".
3. In VS Code, open the `src/component.js` file which is where `index.js` gets the "Hello World" string.
4. Change the string in `src/component.js` to something like "Hello World from Webpack" and save the file.
5. Webpack detects a change in code and updates the `public/bundle.js` file.
6. `liveReload` refreshes the browser, `public/index.html` runs the updated JavaScript code, and the browser automatically updates to display "Hello World from Webpack".

**ACTUAL BEHAVIOR:**

Steps 5 & 6 do not happen as anticipated.

- Step 5 - Webpack successfully detects a change in code, as the terminal shows that files are bundled immediately after `component.js`'s saved changes.

  - Instead of `public/bundle.js` being updated, new `dist/[hash]-main-wps-hmr.js` and `dist/main-[hash]-wps-hrm.json` files are created with hashed names.
  - This behavior really confuses me. I know that "HMR" stands for Hot Module Replacement, but I don't know why these files are being generated instead of my bundled JavaScript file getting updated.

    - The `dist/[hash]-main-wps-hmr.js` looks just like `dist/main.js` except it DOES have the text string updated.
    - The JSON files are all the same single line of code:

      ```
      {"c":["main"],"r":[],"m":[]}
      ```
  - See the terminal message below for additional detail.
- Step 6 - The browser does not automatically refresh to display the changed text.

  - A manual refresh will show the changed text.

**Terminal Message:**

```
> webpack-demo@1.0.0 start
> wp --mode development

⬡ webpack: Watching Files
⬡ wps: Server Listening on: http://[::]:8080

// WHEN component.js IS UPDATED AND SAVED:

⬡ webpack: assets by path *.js 76.2 KiB
    asset main.js 74.7 KiB [emitted] (name: main)
    asset 4bd00c0-main-wps-hmr.js 1.52 KiB [emitted] [hmr] (name: main)
  asset index.html 190 bytes [emitted]
  asset main-4bd00c0-wps-hmr.json 28 bytes [emitted] [hmr]
  Entrypoint main 76.2 KiB = main.js 74.7 KiB 4bd00c0-main-wps-hmr.js 1.52 KiB
  runtime modules 27 KiB 11 modules
  cacheable modules 25.4 KiB

   modules by path ./node_modules/webpack-plugin-serve/lib/client/ 24.2 KiB
   modules by path ./node_modules/webpack-plugin-serve/lib/client/*.js 8.43 KiB
     ./node_modules/webpack-plugin-serve/lib/client/client.js 3.37 KiB [built]
     ./node_modules/webpack-plugin-serve/lib/client/log.js 756 bytes [built]
     + 2 modules
   modules by path ./node_modules/webpack-plugin-serve/lib/client/overlays/*.js 15.7 KiB
     ./node_modules/webpack-plugin-serve/lib/client/overlays/progress-minimal.js 2.41 KiB [built]
     ./node_modules/webpack-plugin-serve/lib/client/overlays/progress.js 3.88 KiB [built]
     + 2 modules
   modules by path ./src/*.js 224 bytes
     ./src/index.js 79 bytes [built]
     ./src/component.js 145 bytes [built] [code generated]
     ./node_modules/webpack-plugin-serve/client.js 1.05 KiB [built]
  0 (webpack 5.89.0) compiled successfully in 49 ms
```

## **CODE**

**src/index.js:**

```
import component from "./component";

document.body.appendChild(component());
```

**src/component.js:**

```
export default (text = "Hello world!") => {
  const element = document.createElement("div");
  element.innerHTML = text;
  return element;
};
```

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "webpack-demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "wp --mode production",
    "start": "wp --mode development",
    "watch": "nodemon --watch \"./webpack.*.*\" --exec \"npm start\""
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "mini-html-webpack-plugin": "^3.1.3",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.1",
    "serve": "^14.2.1",
    "webpack": "^5.89.0",
    "webpack-nano": "^1.1.1",
    "webpack-plugin-serve": "^1.6.0"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js:**

(Does not specify an `output` property, that has not been covered yet in this stage of the tutorial so it should be using the default value).

```
const { mode } = require("webpack-nano/argv");
const {
  MiniHtmlWebpackPlugin,
} = require("mini-html-webpack-plugin");
const { WebpackPluginServe } = require("webpack-plugin-serve");

module.exports = {
  watch: mode === "development",
  entry: ["./src", "webpack-plugin-serve/client"],
  mode,
  plugins: [
    new MiniHtmlWebpackPlugin({ context: { title: "Demo" } }),
    new WebpackPluginServe({
      port: parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 8080,
      static: "./dist",
      liveReload: true,
      waitForBuild: true,
    }),
  ],
};
```

I also tried the following config file based on the `webpack-plugin-serve` [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-plugin-serve) which produces the same unexpected behavior (new hashed files inside dist/, no live reload).

```
const { mode } = require("webpack-nano/argv");
const {
  MiniHtmlWebpackPlugin,
} = require("mini-html-webpack-plugin");

// BELOW LINE CHANGED:
const { WebpackPluginServe: Serve } = require("webpack-plugin-serve");

module.exports = {
  watch: mode === "development",
  entry: ["webpack-plugin-serve/client", "./src"],
  mode,
  plugins: [
    new MiniHtmlWebpackPlugin({ context: { title: "Demo" } }),
    
    // BELOW LINE CHANGED:
    new Serve({
      port: parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 8080,
      static: "./dist",
      liveReload: true,
      waitForBuild: true,
    }),
  ],
};
```